# inserção de dados no mysqli com php

Tags: mysqli

Bom dia pessoal, estou com um problema na inserção de dados no mysqli com php.

Estou usando um formulário com 3 campos: nome, email e senha. O problema é que os dados que insiro no campo email vai parar o campo e senha e vice-versa. E na hora de fazer a validação a me dar problemas me ajudem.

Aqui está o código:

```
public function registro(){
       $db = new Conexao();
       $sql = $db->query("SELECT nome,email FROM usuario WHERE nome='$this->nome' OR email='$this->email';");
       $existe = $db->recorrer($sql);

       if(strtolower($existe['nome'])!=strtolower($this->nome) and strtolower($existe['email'])!=strtolower($this->email)){
        $db->query("INSERT INTO usuario (nome,email,senha) VALUES('$this->nome','$this->email');");   
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $this->nome;
        header('location: Acesso.php');

       } else if(strtolower($existe['nome'])==strtolower($this->nome)){
          header('location: index.php?modo=registro&error=Usuario_usado');  
       }else if(strtolower($existe['email'])==strtolower($this->email)){
        header('location: index.php?modo=registro&error=Email_usado');   

       }
  }
```

formulário

```
<html>
    <head><title>Smart</title></head>
    <body>
     <h1>Registro</h1>   
     {if isset($error)}
          {$error}
         {/if}
     <form action="index.php?modo=registro"method="POST">
         <label>Nome</label><input type="text" name="nome"/><br/><br/>
         <label>Senha</label><input type="password" name="senha"/><br/><br/>
          <label>E-mail</label><input type="email" name="email"/><br/><br/>

<input type="hidden"name="registro" value="1"/>
         <input type="submit"value="Registrar-me"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO usuario (nome,email,senha) VALUES('$this->nome','$this->email');"
```

'thist->senha' ??